# Change a column value if other specific columns with a specific value?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

Consider I have 3 columns:

```
var1 var2 var3 
1    1    1     
0    1    1     
1    0    1    
0    0    1    
1    1    0    
0    1    0    
1    0    0    
0    0    0
```

I want to mutate/change the `var3` column if `var1` and `var2` obey a rule like:

```
var1 and var2 == 1
```

I am trying to do this with `mutate_at`:

```
df %>% mutate_at(.vars = vars(var1, var2, var3), 
                 .funs = funs(ifelse(var1 & var2, var3 = 5, var3 = 2))
```

Please advise what I am missing here, it doesn't work.

Comment: I would do this: `dat$var3 <- c(2, 5)[(var1 == 1 & var2 == 1) + 1L]`.

Comment: @lmo thanks a lot, if possible can you please share mutate_at version? Or similar?

Comment: Why do you need `mutate_at` ? `df %>%
  mutate(var3 = ifelse(var1 == 1 & var2 == 1, 5, 2))` would do ?

Comment: @RonakShah thanks a lot! Just thought I need to insert the if using the `mutate_at`. My mistake, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve the same by many different ways, including `mutate`. You can even do it with `dpplyr::mutate_at`. You need to change logic slightly as:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% mutate_at(vars(c("var3")), funs(ifelse(var1==1 & var2 == 1, 5, 2)))

#   var1 var2 var3
# 1    1    1    5
# 2    0    1    2
# 3    1    0    2
# 4    0    0    2
# 5    1    1    5
# 6    0    1    2
# 7    1    0    2
# 8    0    0    2
```

**Note:** The only motivation I can think of about using `mutate_at` would have been if you had many other columns like `var3`, `var4` etc which were going be processed with similar logic. For just a single column it will just make things more complicated.

**Data:**

```
df <- read.table(text =
"var1 var2 var3 
1    1    1     
0    1    1     
1    0    1    
0    0    1    
1    1    0    
0    1    0    
1    0    0    
0    0    0",
header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `ifelse`

```
library(dplyr)


df <- read.table(text = "
var1 var2 var3 
1    1    1     
0    1    1     
1    0    1    
0    0    1    
1    1    0    
0    1    0    
1    0    0    
0    0    0 ", header = TRUE)


df %>% 
  mutate(var3 = ifelse(var1 == 1 & var2 == 1,
                       2,
                       var3))
```

result:

```
  var1 var2 var3
1    1    1    2
2    0    1    1
3    1    0    1
4    0    0    1
5    1    1    2
6    0    1    0
7    1    0    0
8    0    0    0
```

Answer (score 1):

`case_when` gives a lot of flexibility for rule-making.

````
 df %>% 
  mutate(
      var3 = case_when(
        var1==1 & var2==1 ~ "my.new.variable",
        TRUE ~ as.character(var3)
      )
    )

#> # A tibble: 8 x 3
#>    var1  var2 var3           
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <chr>          
#> 1  1.00  1.00 my.new.variable
#> 2  0     1.00 1              
#> 3  1.00  0    1              
#> 4  0     0    1              
#> 5  1.00  1.00 my.new.variable
#> 6  0     1.00 0              
#> 7  1.00  0    0              
#> 8  0     0    0
```

Created on 2018-06-03 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).
````

Comment: please clarify what `TRUE ~ as.character(var3)` mean? Does it mean if `var1 == 1 & var2 ==1` isn't true, just keep var3?